# How to properly place PolyCollection using offsets?

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to draw a set of identical rectangles using PolyCollection, but I have trouble putting them in the right positions. In the following code, I'd like to put three rectangles centered at specified `offsets` in terms of data coordinates, but they don't show up at the right positions.

```
from matplotlib import collections

subplot_kw = dict(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw, figsize=(5,5))
ivtx = 10 * np.array([-1,-1,1,1])/2.0
jvtx = 20 * np.array([-1,1,1,-1])/2.0
vtx = np.array(zip(jvtx, ivtx))
rectangles = collections.PolyCollection([vtx], offsets=[(0,0),(20,10),(40,60)], transOffset=ax.transData)
ax.add_collection(rectangles)
```

I think the problem is `transOffset`. What is the correct transform?

[image: rectangles are at the wrong offsets]

Answer (score 0):

The role of offsets and transOffset confusingly documented. To use `offsets` in data coordinates for a PolyCollection you need to set the `transOffset` to the identity transform and change the `offset_position` to "data".

```
collections.PolyCollection([vtx], offsets=[(0,0),(20,10),(40,60)], 
                                        transOffset=mtransforms.IdentityTransform(),
                                        offset_position="data")
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

subplot_kw = dict(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw, figsize=(5,5))
ivtx = 10 * np.array([-1,-1,1,1])/2.0
jvtx = 20 * np.array([-1,1,1,-1])/2.0
vtx = np.array(zip(jvtx, ivtx))
rectangles = collections.PolyCollection([vtx], offsets=[(0,0),(20,10),(40,60)], 
                                        transOffset=mtransforms.IdentityTransform(),
                                        offset_position="data")
ax.add_collection(rectangles)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

An alternative is of course to calculate the vertices directly,
i.e. transforming them manually:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subplot_kw = dict(xlim=(-20,70), ylim=(-20, 70))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5),subplot_kw=subplot_kw) #, 
ivtx = 10 * np.array([-1,-1,1,1])/2.0
jvtx = 20 * np.array([-1,1,1,-1])/2.0
vtx = np.array(zip(jvtx, ivtx))

def o(vtx, o):
    vtx = np.copy(vtx)
    vtx[:,0] = vtx[:,0]+o[0]
    vtx[:,1] = vtx[:,1]+o[1]
    return vtx

offsets=[(0,0),(20,10),(40,60)]
rectangles = collections.PolyCollection([o(vtx,offset) for offset in offsets])    
ax.add_collection(rectangles)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That was what I ended up doing. I am still curious how exactly offsets works, though.